# Creating a clear button with gradient border and gradient text

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I'm trying to add a gradient to my UIButton Title and to the border of the button. I've gone through most of the solution on here which I cannot get working for the life of me, might be outdated, I'm not sure. So currently I extend the UIView in order to set the gradient of whatever. So how would I add another function for this feature?

```
func setGradientBackground(colorOne: UIColor, colorTwo: UIColor)  {
    let gradientlayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientlayer.frame = bounds
    gradientlayer.colors = [colorOne.cgColor, colorTwo.cgColor]
    gradientlayer.locations = [0, 1]
    gradientlayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    gradientlayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)

    layer.insertSublayer(gradientlayer, at: 0)

}
```

[image: An Example of what I would like to achieve]

Comment: @MFDOOM What's the question on which you're setting the bounty? The original question is completely unclear. "How would I add another function for this feature?" It's easy to make a view that looks like the image; is that all you want?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have created a demo for you, you can do this with the help of `CAGradientLayer` see the following output and code for this.

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

For gradient button text color and border put your `UIButton` inside `UIView`, then assign `CAGradientLayer` to `UIview`.

**Note:-** Don't forget to set the button as the views mask, See the following code.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var viewForButton: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var myButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // Create a gradient layer
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()

        // gradient colors in order which they will visually appear
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.blue.cgColor]

        // Gradient from left to right
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)

        // set the gradient layer to the same size as the view
        gradient.frame = viewForButton.bounds

        // add the gradient layer to the views layer for rendering
        viewForButton.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

        // Tha magic! Set the button as the views mask
        viewForButton.mask = myButton

        //Set corner Radius and border Width of button
        myButton.layer.cornerRadius =  myButton.frame.size.height / 2
        myButton.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    }

}
```

**Extension**: You can also prefer this extension for the same.

```
extension UIView{

    func gradientButton(_ buttonText:String, startColor:UIColor, endColor:UIColor) {

        let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: self.bounds)
        button.setTitle(buttonText, for: .normal)

        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        self.mask = button

        button.layer.cornerRadius =  button.frame.size.height / 2
        button.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
testView.gradientButton("Hello", startColor: .red, endColor: .blue)
```

Comment: how can I do that in the function I use above though? @AtulParmar

Comment: I implemented as you have but the button just disappears? @AtulParmar

Comment: @OCTAVIAN Simply create a function and pass arguments as you want, you can make a function with parameres like pass start and end color. and if you want to create a function for all/many controllers then pass button and container view as an argument.

Comment: @MFDOOM Looks like you missed something from the above code. Can you please share the code so that I can review it and provide resolution for the same?

Comment: This will won't work If you add UIButton programmatically, since It's bounds won't be  set yet in ViewDidLoad. Can you make it an extension of UIView?

Comment: @EmreÖnder please refer the updated answer. Although the extension can be created with the same code used in viewDidLoad method. It's easy thing to do.

Comment: The extension doesn't work though ... think of it, you're not adding the button to the view

Comment: The button doesn't work: it can't receive touches

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add below UIView extension and call the function to get desire gradient button,

```
func covertToGradientButtonWith(title: String, radius: CGFloat, borderWidth: CGFloat, gradientStartColor: UIColor, gradientEndColor: UIColor) {

    let button:UIButton = UIButton(frame: self.bounds)
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)

    let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [gradientStartColor.cgColor, gradientEndColor.cgColor]
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.5)
    gradient.frame = self.bounds
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    self.mask = button

    button.layer.cornerRadius =  radius
    button.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
}
```

Hope, this solution may help you.